# Hamiltonian ODEs and associated Hamiltonian

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have to find the Hamiltonian associated to the following complex scalar ODE 
$$\dot{z}=i\vert z\vert^2z$$
Can someone give me some hints to solve this problem?

Comment: Please do always provide your own ideas and existing calculations to help to identify your specific problem. In an ideal world, you should be able to separate this equation into its real components and, by comparison, identify the partial derivatives of the Hamiltonian $H$. -- Most curricula follow the pattern "number sets -> continuity of real functions -> differential calculus of real functions -> differential equations". Exercises in one stage serve to strengthen the expertise in the previous stage. One would expect your question to relate to the integration of the vector field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the equation right, but i will try

Let $z = x+iy$. Then $z'=x'+iy'$ and $|z|^2=(x^2+y^2)$. We now can rewrite our equation.

$$x'+iy'=i(x^2+y^2)(x+iy)=-y(x^2+y^2)+ix(x^2+y^2)$$

We get two ODEs by comparing the cofficients of the real and imaginary parts.

$$x'=\frac{dx}{dt}=-y(x^2+y^2)=\partial_yH$$
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dt}=x(x^2+y^2)=-\partial_xH$$

By integrating both equations
$$H = -\frac{1}{2}y^2x^2-\frac{1}{4}y^4+f(x)$$
$$H = -\frac{1}{4}x^4-\frac{1}{2}x^2y^2+g(y)$$

Comparing both equations you get.
$$H=-\frac{1}{4}x^4-\frac{1}{4}y^4-\frac{1}{2}y^2x^2$$

Comment: They are looking for a scalar function $H$ such that $x'=\partial_y H$ and $y'=-\partial_x H$. This $H$ can be read off from your first set of equations.

Comment: Is my answer wrong?

Comment: Partially "wrong", in the sense that you answered a different question in the second half. In the presented facts and solutions, everything is correct.

Comment: Now i tried to solve the real problem :D.

Comment: @LutzL: What was the meaning of my solutions? What would the circles mean in Mechanics?

Comment: Yes, the Hamitlonian is $H=-\frac14(x^2+y^2)^2$. All solutions stay inside the level curves $H=const.$, thus you have correctly identified the level curves (within the previous version of the answer). -- Reinserting $|z|^2=x^2+y^2=c=const.$ into the original equation gives $\dot z=icz$ with solution $z(t)=z(0)·e^{ict}$, the angular velocity depends on the radius of the circle.